# How to give an item a higher 'use' rate when right click is held down?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to get a function to run whenever the player uses a carrot on a stick, however it feels  slow when holding down rightclick since the use time of it is every 4-5 ticks instead of 1. This also makes spam clicking more effective than holding down right click. I did test a command series and it sort of works, however whenever I right click the command gets executed twice at a time, even with just one click:

```
scoreboard players set @a[scores={rclick=1..}] rev 1
scoreboard players reset @a[scores={rclick=1..}] rclick
scoreboard players add @a[scores={rev=1..}] rev 1
scoreboard players set @a[scores={rev=5..}] rev 0

execute as @a[scores={rev=2}] at @s run say hi
execute as @a[scores={rev=4}] at @s run say hi
```

Comment: I think you're going to have to add a few more details.  I don't exactly follow what it is you're trying to accomplish, nor what the exact problem is.

Comment: All the tricks I've tried, replacing an item in the inventory, using a villager for click detection and killing it instantly, swapping between two different methods, …, nothing works. So I think the Vanilla client just simply doesn't send that many click events. You also can't detect pulling a bow or being in the process of eating or something like that, so it might actually be impossible to do what you want.